# How to detect member's custom status and rich presence game status

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to do a member information command that shows the member's current activity/status, where it displays their playing/listening/streaming status if found, and their custom status if found.

I added `if` statements to detected playing, listening, and streaming statuses, and to detect what they are playing/listening to/streaming, and added an `else` statement at the end to detect the custom status, so this way, if the bot finds a status but it is not playing or listening or streaming, then it is a custom status. However, when the user plays a Rich Presence game, the bot counts it as a custom status, and for some reason, the playing statement is not catching it.

My questions are: How do you detect a Rich Presence game member's status, are they the same as normal games or do they have another way to spot them, and how do you detect a member's custom status as well because I couldn't find an answer.

My code:

```
for activity in member.activities:
            if isinstance(activity, Game):
                name = activity.name
                Type = "Playing"
                Activity = f"{name}"
            elif isinstance(activity, Streaming):
                name2 = activity.name
                name3 = activity.platform
                Type = "Streaming"
                Activity = f"{name2} on {name3}"
            elif isinstance(activity, Spotify):
                name4 = activity.title
                name5 = activity.artists
                Type = "Listening to Spotify"
                Activity = f"**Song Name**:{name4}\n**Song Artists:**{name5}"
            else:
                Custom = member.activity
        embed.add_field(name="Activity Type", value=f"{Type}", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Activity Name", value=f"{Activity}", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Custom Status", value=f"{Custom}", inline=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
for activity in member.activities:
    print(type(activity), activity)
```

to see the instance type and activity for each activity, that way you will be able to see what you need to actually match:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to derw's help, I was able to determine which type of activity I should use, For custom status, the type to use is CustomActivity, for rich presence games, I just used an `else` statement.

Code:

```
for activity in member.activities:
            if isinstance(activity, Game):
                name = activity.name
                Type = "Playing"
                Activity = f"{name}"
            elif isinstance(activity, Streaming):
                name2 = activity.name
                name3 = activity.platform
                Type = "Streaming"
                Activity = f"{name2} on {name3}"
            elif isinstance(activity, Spotify):
                name4 = activity.title
                name5 = activity.artists
                Type = "Listening to Spotify"
                Activity = f"**Song Name**:{name4}\n**Song Artists:**{name5}"
            elif isinstance(activity, CustomActivity):
                name6 = activity.name
                Type = "Custom Status"
                Custom = f"{name6}"
            else:
                name7 = activity.name
                Type =  "Playing"
                Activity = f"{name7}"
```

Comment: If you'd like to help out derw you can mark his answer as correct! It will give him some extra reputation and I'm sure they'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to do so earlier, my apologies.